# Pass id of component in setter method to ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

Well, i have a generic setter method in my ManagedBean. This generic method should add the value of a property with the component id into a "Map", see bellow my component in XHTML page:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Data Fechamento: " />
                    <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" required="true"
                        requiredMessage="A Data de Fechamento é obrigatória"
                        value="#{relatorioMB.param}">
                    </p:calendar>
```

Inside my ManagedBean see the setter method "setParam()":

```
public void setParam(Object value){
    String compId = "dataFechamento"; //here should be a generic form to get component id
    AppContext.getInstance().addAttribute(compId, value);
    }
```

All components in my XHTML page will call "setParam()" and ADD a new attribute to "AppContext" class. How can i do it ?

**EDIT 1**

I tried use getCurrentComponent in setter method, but it return the "panelGrid" (parent) and not Calendar.

```
UIComponent ui = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
```

Comment: You're not posting the relevant bits of your view. Where's the PanelGrid you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a handler bean that would take all the params and put them into an array. There you could call `setParam()` for each element in the array using a loop.

An example of this would be:

On your page if you need information from an inputText:

```
<h:inputText id="id" value="#{Handler.id}"></h:inputText>
```

This sets the value on the handler as a field that you can work with.

Then when you have a button call an action from your handler like:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{Handler.doAction}" />
```

Then it is as simple as calling a method from the handler!

Hope this helps!

Comment: really, i can't imagine what your ideia with this. I think that if i could get the ID of current component, the problem is solved.

Comment: See @Josef E., i can't create a lot of "properties" inside a handler because are so much. Inside this "HandleR" i have a propertie 'Map<String,Object> params', and i wanna put each 'ID + VALUE' of component from JSF to this Handler. Do you understand ?